# angularjs get previous element of clicked button inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How do you get the previous element of the clicked element that is inside a `ng-repeat` using AngularJS? In jquery, this could be done using `$(this).prev()` or something equivalent.

For an instance I have this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="UserController as vm">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.users">
        <td>{{value.username}}</td>
        <td><button name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.delete(key)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then on my `UserController`:

```
function UserController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.delete = function(buttonId) {
        // get the clicked element and get previous element
        // "this" doesn't work as it returns the vm itself
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Should be returning the `<td>` element of `vm.username`

Comment: use vm.users($index-1) but 0 will not have a previous element to pass inside delete

Comment: you can pass value.username if you want the username value. Why do you want td HTMLElement ?

Comment: Just saw something about `$event` wherein I could get the attributes of the selected element like `event.target.id` on the controller. But it seems that `event` doesn't have a `previous` property? Though it has `previousElementSibling` and `previousSibling` but it is not what I am looking for to get the previous element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
ng-click="vm.delete(key,$index)"
```

and your controller code should be

```
function UserController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.delete = function(buttonId,index) {
      if(index > 0){
       var result = vm.users[index-1].username
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be a slight modification in the condition. it should be `if(index > 1){...}`